Trouble creating instance of Ethernet/IP class -Powershell
it keeps telling me the assemblies are not loaded (even though I have set them up at the top)
    # Load the EEIP.dll
    Add-Type -Path C:\myDlls\EIP\EEIP.dll
    Add-Type Sres.Net.EEIP
    # Define PLC connection parameters
    $IPAddress = "192.168.1.190"
    $Timeout = 2000  # Timeout value in milliseconds
    try {
        # Create an instance of the Ethernet/IP communication class
        $plc = New-Object EthernetIP.EEIPClient
    }
    catch {
         Write-Host "Error communicating with PLC:" $_.Exception.Message
    }

it seems to work ok in VS (VS is also pointed to the same dll location specified in the PS script)
    using Sres.Net.EEIP;
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EEIPClient eeipClient = new EEIPClient();
            eeipClient.RegisterSession("192.168.1.190");
            eeipClient.UnRegisterSession();
        }
    }

I have tried loading a dll that I know works. I then tried it with the dll that does not work and the output I received is not so promising
try
{
   Add-Type -Path "C:\myDlls\EIP\EEIP.dll"
   #Add-Type -Path "C:\OPC\OpcComRcw.dll"
}
catch [System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException]
{
   Write-Host "Message: $($_.Exception.Message)"
   Write-Host "StackTrace: $($_.Exception.StackTrace)"
   Write-Host "LoaderExceptions: $($_.Exception.LoaderExceptions)"
}

Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\myDlls\EIP\EEIP.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
that part was fixed by right clicking dll, properties, and check the unblock box. restarted powershell
still having the issue with creating instance of Ethernet/IP class

https://github.com/rossmann-engineering/EEIP.NET/issues might be a good place for questions such as this.

changed this
$plc = New-Object EthernetIP.EEIPClient

to this
[Sres.Net.EEIP.EEIPClient]$ethernetIP = New-Object Sres.Net.EEIP.EEIPClient

